# Calling a function after or before tearDown of each unit testcase

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a function removeElements() which needs to be called in teardown of every testcase. Is there any way I can call this function automatically when teardown rather than copying the function call in each testcase?

Comment: Which testing module are you using? It's pretty hard to answer without knowing that…

Comment: i am using unittest.TestCase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you already know about the `testCase` method, and you already know how to inherit implementations, and the only thing you're missing is how to inherit implementations but still allow customization.

The simplest way to do this is to create an intermediate class or mixin class that implements the `tearDown` hook. For example, let's say you're writing test cases like this:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        print('Tearing down {}'.format(self))
```

… but you want them all to call `removeElements`.

Define this intermediate class:

```
class ElementRemovingTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        self.removeElements()
```

And now write your cases this way instead:

```
class MyTestCase(ElementRemovingTestCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        super(MyTestCase, self).tearDown()
        print('Tearing down {}'.format(self))
```

If you don't want to pass `tearDown` up the method-resolution chain so you can save one line of code in each test case, you can just define a new hook protocol instead:

```
class ElementRemovingTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        self.removeElements()
        self.additionalTearDown()

class MyTestCase(ElementRemovingTestCase):
    def additionalTearDown(self):
        print('Tearing down {}'.format(self))
```

And any of the other usual options for OO in Python will work here, no matter how crazy you want to get:

```
for name, case in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], 
                                     lambda cls: issubclass(cls, unittest.TestCase)):
    real_tearDown = case.tearDown
    def tearDown(self):
        self.removeElements()
        real_tearDown(self)
    case.tearDown = real_tearDown
```

Answer (score 1):

Python [unittest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#module-unittest) has a [tearDown()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) method that you can use:

```
import unittest

class ElementTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        addElements()

    def tearDown(self):
        removeElements()

    #define test cases...
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, but suppose there are 100 test cases i need to call removeElements in all testcases. Wanted to know is there any other way I can make teardown internally call remove elements by itself.

Comment: unittest calls setUp and tearDown automatically for each test run. From the unittest link above: "When a setUp() method is defined, the test runner will run that method prior to each test. Likewise, if a tearDown() method is defined, the test runner will invoke that method after each test"